# Azure Function BlobTrigger doesnt capture all incoming events

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

with a very simple Azure Function program, I will test Azure Event Grid. My goal is if a file is uploaded to Storage account, then my Azure function should be triggered and log a message like `Hello World`. I have this block of code in my Azure Function:

```
namespace BlobTrigger
{
    public static class BlobEventGrid
    {
        [FunctionName("BlobEventGrid")]
        public static void Run([EventGridTrigger]JObject eventGridEvent,
            [Blob("{data.url}", Connection = "BlobConnection")] string file,
            TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

I have set my Event grid from this [article](http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Improving-Azure-Functions-Blob-Trigger-Performance-and-Reliability-Part-3-Using-Event-Grid-to-Respond-to-New-Blobs).

If I upload more than 50 file to my container, and then control the Live Metrics of my Azure Functions I can only see 4 incoming events:

[image]

By controlling metrics in event subscription, I see such metrics:

[image]

Delivered Events:66
Matched Events: 51

Do you have any Idea, why I only 4 events are tracked by my azure functions?

Comment: I had a bunch of trouble getting blob triggers to work consistently, ended up switching to a different trigger (maybe event grid?) which basically worked the same.

Comment: As you can see I try to use Event Grid in Azure Functions, or do you mean something else?

Comment: No sorry, I misread the question, assumed you were using `BlobTrigger`

Comment: Do you have any example for event Grid for Azure Function V1?

Comment: Have you checked if each Function invocation actually contains more than one event? This looks like the event data is an array: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fblobs%2ftoc.json

Comment: Actually in each trace (in my situation 4 traces instead of 50 traces) I see only one unque file, and not an array